# Fail at sending byte array through serial port excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel, winapi, serial-port

I am trying to get information from an Excel worksheet and send it through a serial port as a byte array, using Windows API. This is just a small part of it:

```
lngSize = UBound(byteData) - LBound(byteData)
WriteFile(udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle, byteData, lngSize, _lngWrSize, udtCommOverlap)
```

My current problem: when I am sending a byte array of length 1 (just one byte), I receive it correctly (I am using a hyperterminal to check what I'm sending), but when I send an array of length > 1, here comes the problem; instead of receiving it like this:

```
letter = 65
For i = 0 To 5
    dataToSend(i) = letter
    letter = letter + 1
Next
```

[what I should receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiDBb.png)

what I get is this:

[what I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cny7r.png)

I really cannot figure out what could be the problem and I would be grateful if someone had a clue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the correct number of elements in an array is:

```
lngSize = UBound(byteData) - LBound(byteData) + 1     ' <-- add 1
```

More importantly, your code is not applying the [call convention for the `WriteFile API`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx). Namely, the second parameter should be a `LPCVOID` pointer to the first Byte to transfer. Passing the array's name `byteData` to the function wont achieve that, because the array is a complex `COM` data structure, not like a `C` array. What you should do is:

- First get the `address` of the array's data structure, using `VarPtrArray`:
- Then add `12` to it to get the address of the first byte.

.

```
Private Declare Function VarPtrArray Lib "VBE7" Alias "VarPtr" (var () As Any) As Long

...

WriteFile(udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle, VarPtrArray(byteData()) + 12, lngSize, _lngWrSize, udtCommOverlap)
'                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For information about handling arrays' data and their pointers, excellent examples can be found [on this page].(https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/729235/VB-and-VBA-Array-Buffering)

Also make sure that you declared you array as a `Byte` array, like

```
Redim byteData(someSize) As Byte
'                        ^^^^^^^
```

There might be other errors in the parts of code you didn't show (possibly the settings of `udtCommOverlap`), but hopefully these corrections will put you on the right track.

Comment: Sorry, I've uploaded the same photo twice - it is ok now. I made the change in the code, but I am still getting the wrong thing (but with one byte more)

Comment: Also, it works on strings. I can send strings and receive them exactly as sent.

Comment: First, I tried what you suggested , that VarPtrArray(byteData())+12, but it wasn't a success. But then I thought to just pass the first byte of the array, so I wrote instead of VarPtrArray(byteData())+12 byteData(0) and it worked. Thank you so much for your help, you guided me to the right path:)